# Issues regarding annotations on Roboflow

Tags: computer-vision, roboflow

I hope I get some assistance regarding this :)

So I made a custom data set on Roboflow with around 100+ images. I used 2 tags - front and back to detect front and back of cars using instance segmentation. However, when I am checking the annotations.json file, I am shown that I have 3 tag ids instead of 2 (front, back, front). I am really confused about this and this is the 2nd dataset of mine that has similar issue. Can someone please let me know if there are any roboflow tools itself that can help me fix this issue? Thank you so much in advance! Any guidance is appreciated.

I made sure to not create more than 2 classes, but I might be missing out on something crucial that I don't know about yet.